# Pink Glue Leaking

Tags: adhesive

I have a newly built house, 1 1/2 years old. Pink glue still leaks from a couple sections of my flooring. Why is this still happening? I live in Chesapeake Va and the flooring is on a concrete slab. Thanks

Comment: Any chance you have a picture?

Comment: a glue that has not hardened in days.weeks.months is not a glue

Comment: before we assume the flooring is wood. Tell us what type of flooing it is.

Comment: And any possibility that the slab has humidity/water leak problems? Like others, I don't remember ever seeing a pink flooring adhesive, but the fact that it's wet could be that they put some water-based something that has not cured.

Answer (score 0):

Flooring adhesive is typically a yellow, brown, or off-white. I cannot imagine that someone would add a pink tint to it. It sounds like the wrong product was applied beneath your floors.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Contact your general contractor and report this issue. The flooring contractor needs to be brought back to fix this.